# Snap to empty point in space

Tags: snapping

**Sketchup** has this snap function whereby the cursor can **snap to an empty point in space** that has the same X, Y or Z coordinate as a certain vertex somewhere else in space. As soon as the cursor comes in the vicinity of **one of the three coordinates** of that vertex, the vertex lights up and you can snap the cursor to that single coordinate value (and not to that vertex). This allows for quick and correctly line drawing 90° angled geometric forms (like a cube) in 3D mode.

**Is there a similar snap functionality in Blender?** To my knowledge, the Blender cursor can only snap to a grid or to a vertex (or edge) itself.

**ADDED**: OK, this is what Sketchup can do, explained in Blender language:

you start from a vertex in 3D space. You draw a first edge by creating a second vertex. For the third vertex (second edge), you want to make a 90° angle with the first edge. Can you restrict ("snap") the cursor so that the second edge is always orthogonal to the first edge? Going further to the fourth vertex (third edge), can you restrict the movement of the cursor so that the third edge is always parallel to the first edge? And finally, can you restrict the cursor movement so that the third edge and first edge have the same length? If yes, you can **draw** (so not using a preset shape) a rectangle in 3D space.

This functionality also allows to select a random edge in your project, and then start somewhere else in space from a selected vertex an edge that runs parallel ("snap") to the random edge, and that even can be set ("snap") to the same length as that random edge.

Comment: I don't think I understand your question...*empty point in space that has the same X, Y or Z coordinate as a **certain vertex somewhere else in space***. Is there, or is there not a vertex?

Comment: Instead of telling us, what sketchups workflow is and trying to recreate it in Blender, explain what you're actually trying to achieve. E.g. "How do i easily create a 90° angle?" / "This is my geomtry [image], how can I create that point?"

Comment: Not sure if you know about the possibility to lock axes by either middle button click or hitting "x", "y", or "z" while a command is active (e.g. moving a vertex. Locking axes while having vertex snap on may achieve what I think you may be after. Let me know if you would like me to elaborate further.